# Get value from Another Stored procedure(B) in a stored Procedure(A)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure ssspAccProfitAndLoss which returns result as shown below:

[image]

I have another stored procedure named ssspAccBalanceSheet. In this store procedure i have a variable declared as

```
Declare totalProfitAndLoss decimal(18,0)
```

I want the Total sum of Amount1 column of ssspAccProfitAndLoss and set it to totalProfitAndLoss. How can i achieve this.

```
Set totalProfitAndLoss = Select Sum(Amount1) from ssspAccProfitAndLoss
```

Thanxxxxx in advance....

Comment: why dont you think about using an `output parameter` in `ssspAccProfitAndLoss`. Which contains sum of `Amount1`

Comment: Yeaaa i used that but i am using edmx model for my c# project, and i am not able to call the stored procedure if i use output parameter. It accepts System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter and i dont have any idea how to create one and pass it into the storedprocedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to change the ssspAccProfitAndLoss procedure you probably need to work through variable table - if the ssspAccProfitAndLoss is short running SP than it's probably acceptable.

```
declare @totalProfitAndLoss decimal(18,0); --I'd go for BIGINT here unless you're sure you need 18 digits
declare @resultTable table (
    Particular varchar(100),
    Amount decimal(18,0),
    Particular2 varchar(100),
    Amount2 decimal(18,0));
insert into @resultTable exec ssspAccProfitAndLoss
select @totalProfitAndLoss = sum(Amount1) from @resultTable
```